# Android Studio "Error:Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: > 'getProguard()'!" after upgrading

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I just upgraded my Android Studio preview release to the latest beta 0.8.3 and my gradle build script which was working perfectly fine until now fails with this:

> Error:Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found:
>   'getProguard()'!

Running the script in the command line with `--stacktrace` gives me:

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: Could not
>   find method getProguard() for arguments [] on
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@21939397.

As far as I know, I don't even have a ProGuard task configured for this project.

Android Studio is set to use the default gradle wrapper and querying the version shows I'm using gradle version 1.10.

Comment: Could you paste your build.gradle for the project

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that Studio 0.8.3 is a [canary release](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio083released), and bugs are **to be expected**.

Since updating to 0.8.3 seems to be the change that broke your build, I can only suggest that you [file a bug report](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html) to the dev team and then downgrade and/or reinstall a [more stable release](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#download).

Comment: I just downgraded to 0.6.0 (preview) release from 7 months back.. and I'm getting the same error (!!).

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe try one more time with a beta version (one was released just the other week), and double-check that no code has changed since it last worked. I have found that even tiny changes can break Gradle badly :(